# How do I post Seach Textbox data alongside DataSourceRequest

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I am trying to send my toolbar's 'search textbox' value through to a WEB API action.  I have searched various online solutions. However, none seem to work.

On the client-side, I have a 'KeyUp' event on the 'search textbox'.  Once completed, I need to append the value to the READ.

**I HAVE TRIED THE FOLLOWING (CLIENT-SIDE):**

```
// This Fails
var value = dictionary.elements.txtDeviceSearch.val();
var url = "api/devicedataitem/search?text='" + value + "'";

dictionary.instances.gridDevices.dataSource.options.transport.read.url = url;
dictionary.instances.gridDevices.dataSource.read();

// This Fails
dictionary.instances.gridDevices.dataSource.options.transport.read.data = { text: value };
dictionary.instances.gridDevices.dataSource.read();

// This Fails
dictionary.instances.gridDevices.dataSource.read({ text: 'Work Dammit' });
```

[image]

**THE INITIAL CALL WORKS AS EXPECTED:**
This is working as expected...

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<DeviceDataItem>()
    .Name("gridDevices")
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .WebApi()
        .Model(model =>
        {
            model.Id(m => m.DeviceId);
            model.Field(m => m.DeviceName);
            model.Field(m => m.CommunicationTechnicianId);
            model.Field(m => m.CommunicationTechnicianFullName);
            model.Field(m => m.MeasurementTechnicianId);
            model.Field(m => m.MeasurementTechnicianFullName);
        })
        .Read(read => read.Url("api/devicedataitem/search?text=''").Type(HttpVerbs.Post))
    )
    .ToolBar(toolbar =>
    {
        toolbar.Template(@<text>
            <div class="input-group pull-right" role="toolbar">
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id='txtDeviceSearch' placeholder="Search for..." />
            </div>
        </text>);
    })
    .Deferred(true))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I finally figured this one out & it was difficult.  This particular answer has many facets:

- It uses a GET
- As such, the GET requires use of the "Model Binder Attribute"
- A minor POST example is now included below...

**GET - WEB API:** 
This works because the "Model Binder Attribute" grabs the REQUEST object & hydrates it for you.  Without it, the REQUEST will always be **null**.

```
// GET: /api/DeviceDataItem/Search
[HttpGet]
public DataSourceResult Search([ModelBinder(typeof(WebApiDataSourceRequestModelBinder))] DataSourceRequest request, string search)
{
    var application = (MyApplication)Application;
    var provider = (DeviceDataItemProvider)application.DeviceDataItemProvider;

    IQueryable<DeviceDataItem> query = provider.Query();

    // No 'Where' needed
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(search))
        return query.ToDataSourceResult(request);

    // Where
    ...your WHERE logic goes here...

    return query.ToDataSourceResult(request);
}
```

**GET - MVC.Read:** 
Notice I am referring to a custom `Page Controller` object that is publicly available through the window.

```
.Read(read => read.Url(Url.HttpRouteUrl("DefaultApi", new { controller = "DeviceDataItem", action="Search"}))
                          .Type(HttpVerbs.Get)
                          .Data("window.pageController.on.read.gridDevices"))
```

**GET - JavaScript:** 
I happen to cache my objects in a Page Controller - you will have to reference your objects (however they are built).

```
this.on = {
    read: {
        gridDevices: function () {
            return {
                search: dictionary.elements.txtDeviceSearch.val()
            }
        }
    },
    search: {
        gridDevices: function (e) {

            lazyInitGridDevices();

            // Clear
            dictionary.instances.gridDevices.dataSource.data([]);
            dictionary.instances.gridDevices.refresh();

            // Read
            dictionary.instances.gridDevices.dataSource.read();
        }
    }
};
```

**POST:** 
According to Telerik, the same approach is used for passing parameters to POST requests. However, with Web API, the second parameter cannot be added to the method signature. One possible way to address this scenario is to use a JObject to get all the data from the request and then construct a new model object using this data.

For example:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post(JObject jsonData)
{
    ProductViewModel product = new ProductViewModel() {
        ProductName = (string)jsonData["ProductName"],
        UnitPrice = (decimal)jsonData["ProductID"],
        UnitsInStock = (int)jsonData["ProductName"],
        Discontinued = (bool)jsonData["ProductID"]
    };
    string searchTerm = (string)jsonData["search"];

    .............
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Now we're getting somewhere, this question is better than the other one. What I was about to say back then, before giving up is that there is a parameter called [`parameterMap`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-transport.parameterMap) in the JavaScript widget where you can manipulate the data which will be sent in the request to API. As stated in the docs you could try:

```
parameterMap: function (data, type) {
    return kendo.stringify($.extend({ "text": $("#txtDeviceText").text() }, data));
}
```

But I don't know how to add it to the razor helper because their docs sucks too much and I can't test it. So you can try:

1. Adding the parameter in the initialization(which I'm not sure if works):

   ```
   DataSource(dataSource => dataSource.ParameterMap("jsFunctionNameHere")
   ```

   Or something like that;
2. Setting it in your grid after initialization:

   ```
   $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.transport.parameterMap = function() {
       return { text: $("#txtDeviceText").text() };
   };
   ```

   [Demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/IpOju)

I bet on 2nd option, it should work.

Comment: Hahahahahahahahahahah...that was hilarious...I love it :-)

Comment: Sorry "parameterMap = function" fails.  This is killing me...hahahaha

Comment: What do you mean with *fails* ? Any error or it just doesn't runs ?

Comment: "text" WEB API param is still empty

Comment: @PrisonerZERO but it at least runs the `parameterMap` function? And it adds the param in the url? Note that it adds the param to the uri, so you may have to add `[FromUri] string text` in your API method.

Comment: The "text" WEB API param is still empty...ugh!  I hate Kendo.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154455/discussion-between-prisoner-zero-and-dontvotemedown).

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
dictionary.instances.gridDevices.dataSource.type = "aspnetmvc-ajax";
```

We do the same thing within our application, sending parameters to the controller action in addition to the DataSourceRequest object. With that type setting removed, I get the same behaviour you do with the parameters received with null values.

The datasource is defined with js akin to this:

```
this.results = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    type: "aspnetmvc-ajax",
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: "Controller/Search",
            data: function () {
                return {
                    value: "abc"
                };
            }
       }
    }
});
```

When read() is triggered on it, it hits the controller action like this:

```
public JsonResult Search([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, string value)
```

So nothing out of the ordinary there but with that type removed, the value is not received. Note that this is a System.Web.MVC.Controller, not a System.Web.Http.ApiController, although I can't see how that would make a difference. It may also be that the datasource type can only effectively be set at the time it is set up (so it would go in the definition, not altered after the fact as I originally suggested) but that's just another guess. I feel your pain - this sort of thing should just work.

Comment: Can possibly you post the following sample pieces so I can look at them: The WEB API signature used, the READ URL used, the relevant JavaScript pieces?  I MUST BE MISSING SOMETHING -Thanks